# Probability of hitting a deep downswing in a sequence

Tags: probability, dice

This is really a poker tournament/payout/bankroll question but I think I can frame it in a dice game for easier understanding.
If a player starts with $X$ units, and plays a game where on each throw the cost/payouts are:

1,2 or 3 = -1

4: = 0

5: = +1

6: = +3

If the players wealth is never allowed to rise above $X$, ie, hits a 6 with a current wealth of $(X-1)$ the new wealth is only $X$, the extra two units are ditched.
Is there an algorithm/formula to predict/plot the chance of ruin over many throws?

There is a Risk of Ruin formula for when the wealth is unrestricted and this, I think, is

$RoR(X) = e^{-aX}$, where $a$ is a constant related to the relative likelihood and expectations but is there a simple formula for when the max wealth is capped?

Or any clues to how to find a reasonable solution?

In the real results I would like to solve there are more outcomes - perhaps 20 or so +ve outcomes out of 100.

Comment: If the player keeps playing, she will be ruined with probability $1$.

Comment: True, ruin is certain with enough throws, I should have asked for the probability of survival after n throws.

Comment: A more or less explicit procedure for determining this has been supplied by Ross Millikan. From this you can determine a fairly simple dominant term for the probability that you ask for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to make a [stochastic matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) where $P_{i,j}$ is the probability of transitioning from $i$ to $j$.  For $i$ and $j$ far enough from $0$ and $X$, you will have $P_{i,i-1}=1/2,P_{i,i}=1/6,P_{1,i+1}=1/6,P_{i,i+3}=1/6$  there will be modifications at the ends.  Your starting vector has $1$ in the last position and $0$ everywhere else.  Then the probability distribution after $n$ plays is $P^n$ times your starting vector.  The calculation can be eased if you diagonalize the matrix so $P=SDS^{-1}$ where $D$ is diagonal.  Then $P^n=SD^nS^{-1}$

Comment: Thanks Ross. I'll look into this.